# semantic of having to declare an attached local into detachable attribute with mandatory check

Tags: eiffel

As far as I understood the `check` with `then` is mandatory.

So what is the semantic of having to declare a local to avoid compiling error (`object could be void`)?

```
detachable dog: DOG

take_a_walk
    do
        check
            attached_dog: attached dog as l_dog
        then
            leash (l_dog) -- why not just leash (dog)?
            walk
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 major reasons why an attribute of a detachable type cannot be used after its voidness test as attached:

1. As soon as a sequence of calls after the voidness test involves more than just a single call, it becomes next to impossible to figure out whether the attribute is still attached or not. Here is an example with an attribute `x`:

   ```
   if attached x then
       foo
       x.bar
   end
   ```

   The call to `foo` can assign `Void` to attribute `x`. Therefore, the call `x.bar` is now unsafe (can lead to the call on `Void` target). In language terms, `x` should be considered as detachable regardless of the earlier voidness test. (Compare this to the use when `x` is a local variable: the call to `foo` cannot change `x`, and the call `x.bar` is fine.)
2. In a multi-threaded environment, the value of an attribute could be changed under the hood. Let's consider the following example with an attribute `x`:

   ```
   if attached x then
       x.bar
   end
   ```

   Here is an execution sequence that leads to the problem:

   - Attribute `x` is tested for voidness and `attached x` gives `True`.
   - Another thread gets control and executes `x := Void`.
   - The control is returned to the original thread, and the call `x.bar` is performed on `Void` target.

As in example 1, if `x` were a local variable, the code would be just fine.

All the reasoning above assumes that an attribute can be assigned `Void`. What if this is false, i.e. when such assignments are impossible? In such a case the attribute can be marked as `stable`:

```
x: detachable FOO
    note
        option: stable
    attribute
    end
```

Then, in terms of void safety, the attribute behaves as a local variable, all the code snippets above become valid and compile without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because the attribute could become set to void in another thread